# Avoid caching of jenkins pipeline scripts

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We are using jenkins pipeline and groovy scripts to do automated build pipeline steps.

However, jenkins has decided to cache previous version of these script files and I have yet to figure out how to clear this cache or how to force load the newer version of these scripts.

The scripts are coming from a git repository and executed through a Jenkninsfile bootstrapper loading scripts using the `myscript = load "@script/path/to/script.groovy"` syntax.

It is these script.groovy files that are not "updated".

Comment: Is this when it logs `Library ... is cached. Copying from home.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we had it sorted out. Someone changed the casing on on of the folders.
Jenkins does not delete the previous folder, but keeps it. Scripts were still pointing to the previous cased folder but jenkins was pulling the updates to the new cased folder.

Answer (score 0):

In "Manage Jenkins -> System", under "Global Pipeline Libraries", there is a button "Clear cache".

Clicking it clears the cache.

In the same section, you can configure how long libraries are cached.